# Cannot run grack, passenger occurs error: uninitialized constant GitHttp (NameError)"

Tags: apache-2.2, http, git, phusion-passenger, ruby

I trying to setup web server for publish git repositories on successfully installed and worked redmine server.

Passenger occurs error:
Web application could not be started

uninitialized constant GitHttp (NameError)
  config.ru:16:in `block in <main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`instance_eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in`new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:105:in`eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:105:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:150:in`'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/passenger-4.0.18/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in`'

/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby

Comment: I Ask developer. See https://github.com/schacon/grack/issues/20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GitHttp` is [a class in released versions of grack (last is 0.2)](https://github.com/schacon/grack/blob/v0.2/lib/git_http.rb) which does not exist anymore in project's git master branch.

I suspect you updated your grack code to master HEAD without updating `config.ru`. Your `config.ru` for master should [be like this](https://github.com/schacon/grack/blob/master/config.ru), with project path replaced :

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib')

use Rack::ShowExceptions

require 'grack'
require 'git_adapter'

config = {
  :project_root => "/path/to/your/repos/",
  :adapter => Grack::GitAdapter,
  :git_path => '/usr/bin/git',
  :upload_pack => true,
  :receive_pack => true,
}

run Grack::App.new(config)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is solved my problem. I use old article from redmine wiki. And error stops me.